# Need to fetch a part of html data sent back through ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I need to fetch a part of HTML data sent back by the controller in response to an ajax call. Need to use the ID

I am not able to use the find function directly on the data...since it is either an object or variable

```
$.get(url, function (data, status) {
```

Here data has the html result

Comment: What value is returned in the data?

Answer (score 0):

assign an ID to the part of html that you want to fetch and use the following

```
 $.get(url, function (data, status) {
 $("#targetID").html($(data).find('#someDiv').html());
 }
```